# "TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API" when using str.rstrip()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to delete some unnecessary characters from my email content using the `rstrip` method. I tried debugging the program using `print(r)`, but I get this error:

```
File "/home/******/Desktop/loung/imap.py", line 23, in signin 
r = raw_email.rstrip('\r\n')
TypeError: Type str doesn 't support the buffer API
```

What does this mean ?
My code is below:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter, imaplib,email
def signin(w,x,s):
        tkgui = tkinter.Tk()
        tkgui.title('Inbox %s'%w)
        mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(('%s'%s),993)
        mail.login(('%s'%w ), ('%s'%x))
        mail.list()
        mail.select("INBOX")
        result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
        ids = data[0]
        id_list = ids.split()
        tree = ttk.Treeview(tkgui)
        for i in range(-1,0):       
                result, data = mail.fetch(id_list[i], '(RFC822)')
                raw_email = data[0][1]
                d = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
                tree.insert('',0,value=(d['Date'],d['From'],d['Subject']))
        tree['columns']=['Date','From','Subject']
        r=raw_email.rstrip('\r\n')
        print(r)
        for col in tree['columns']:
            tree.heading(col,text=col)
        tree.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        tkgui.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the point of a for loop that executes exactly once?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it means that you need to use bytes instead of str, in particular, add a 'b' prefix to `'\r\n'` to get `b'\r\n'`.  `raw_email` is bytes and you can only strip bytes from it.  `d`, on the other hand, is an str instance. which is why using strings with it works.

I believe the obscure error message was recently changed to hopefully be more comprehensible.

Comment: The message means what I said (in 3.x) and you should give me credit for answering your question.  If you pass a bytes object and get a different error message, that is a different problem and potential question.

Comment: It worked for me. I had raw line form  gz file which contained the binary data. Now it is working with `str.rstrip(b'\n');`